# Improving AngularJS performance with constant expressions and manual view refresh

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Lately I was thinking about performance of AngularJS application when you need to present rich domain model (lots of `ngRepeat` and expressions `{{}}` - e.g. rendering spread-sheet-like model).

I came up with pretty simple solution using constat watch expressions and `ngRepeat` over a `stamp` (*revision*) property - [**check plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rJxkoHZi29o5QGdG83gZ?p=preview):

```
<!-- Outer ngRepeat is on a watched dummy object - when changed, ngRepeat will re-generate its contents -->
<ul ng-repeat="stamp in [data.stamp]">
  <!-- Inner constant ngRepeat, which can be pretty expensive in case of long iterations -->
  <li ng-repeat="item in ::data.items">
    Item {{::item.value}}. 
  </li>
</ul>
```

My question is: **Is there any directive specifically for this approach (i.e. refreshing contents when a specified watched value changes)?** Using `ngRepeat` does the job, but feels a bit hacky (no need for a child scope).

And also: **Do you see any issue with the proposed approach?**

One remaining bottleneck I see is that with `ngRepeat` a lot of scopes are still being created and `$rootScope.broadcast` can get a bit expensive. But overall this can greatly improve page performance.

Comment: `ngRepeat` is slow. You're better off to just build a template once via JS and then `$compile` it. You can then use constants for your grid references in the expressions like `items[x][y]`

Comment: I would recommend re-using angular directives where it makes sense. If you need speed, create your own custom directives, and manipulate the DOM, and hookup event handlers yourself, so that you can control when $scope.$apply is called.